# Invoke a system command and pipe a variable as an argument

Tags: r, bash

I'm trying to pass a system command, using the `system2` function, but I want to pass a variable as an argument to the function.

More specifically I have a bash command, `xml-to-json`, that I want to run from R on an object containing XML.

I *could* write this data to file and then run `system2` a second time, but I'd like to keep this as parsimonious as possible.

Comment: are you trying to run the `xml-to-json` program on an object stored in memory in your R session?

Comment: Yes. That is what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

The `input` argument to `system2` does what you want:

> input: if a character vector is supplied, this is copied one string
>             per line to a temporary file, and the standard input of
>             ‘command’ is redirected to the file.

Example:

```
foo = c("foo", "bar")
result = system2("cat", input = foo, stdout = TRUE)
```