# responding yes to terminal prompt via system2() in R

Tags: r

**tl;dr**: How can I invoke the system command `y | conda create --name gee_interface` from an R console, e.g. via system2()?  I'm comfortable enough with `system2('conda', c('create', '--name', 'gee_interface'))`, but I don't know how to handle piping in the 'y' via `system2()`.

**Details**
I am trying to use an R console to run the bash command `conda create --name gee_interface` (OSX Mojave with Anaconda installed).

In terminal, that command executes just fine, but prompts me to answer with `Proceed ([y]/n)?` (I answer 'y' and everything works smoothly).

In R, I run

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(c("/Applications/anaconda3/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH")), collapse = .Platform$path.sep)) # ensures that system2() finds conda

system2('conda', c('create', '--name', 'gee_interface')) # This is the key line for the purposes of this question
```

When running the second line [i.e. `system2('conda', c('create', '--name', 'gee_interface'))`], the process never finishes, but quickly falls to zero CPU usage. Presumably the system is waiting for my response to the prompt, but I don't know how to provide it. How does one do this via an R script? Note also that in my particular case, the number of times that I need to respond 'y' is variable, depending on whether an environment of the name `gee_interface` already exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

The fix to your first problem is to tell `conda` not to ask for confirmation using `-y`:

```
system2('conda', c('create', '--name', 'gee_interface', '-y'))
```

As to the second part (variable times that your input is required), I'm guessing it's to overwrite the environment if it exists? In that case, you could check for its existence first with `conda info --envs`, and run `conda remove --name gee_interface --all` if necessary before creating it.

See:

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment

---

You could also try your `system2` call, with the argument `input = "y"`, but that doesn't fix your second problem of needing to affirm multiple times.

See: [Invoke a system command and pipe a variable as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239069/invoke-a-system-command-and-pipe-a-variable-as-an-argument)